# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command'. Spring exception

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i'm starting learning spring MVC3, and i would like to display a simple "search form" here my jsp file

```
<form:form method="post" action="addGeo.html" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>        
                <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.addzone"/>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</form:form>

<form:form method="post" action="maingeo.html" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="codeZone"><spring:message code="label.area"/></form:label>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <form:input path="codeZone" />
            </td>        
            <td>
                <form:label path="type"><spring:message code="label.type"/></form:label>
            </td>  
            <td>
                <form:input path="type" />
            </td>        
            <td>
                <form:label path="codePostal"><spring:message code="label.departement"/></form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="codePostal" />
            </td>
            <td>        
                <input  type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.searchArea"/>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</form:form>
```

and here my controller :

```
@Controller
public class RefGeoController {

@Autowired  
private RefGeoService refgeoService;        

    @RequestMapping("/maingeo")
    public String goSearchArea() {
        return "maingeo";
    } 
}
```

when i go to this url page, i've got this exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute . I think that i forgot something in my form or maybe in my controller but i dont know where. Moreover what should i put on my method parameter when i don't want to send specific model to my jsp view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an Class, that contains the fields of your form - this kind of class is called Command-Object/Class.

Then in your Controller method, that is responsible for providing the form page, you need to create an instance of this Command-Object, put it in the Model and then let the view render it. The name that is used for the Command-Object in the Model, must match the "command" attribute name of the `<form:form command="myCommand">` tag. If you don't have this attribute, than the default name is `command`.

```
@Controller public class RefGeoController {

   @Autowired private RefGeoService refgeoService;        

   @RequestMapping("/maingeo")
   public ModelAndView goSearchArea() {
      return new ModelAndView("maingeo", "searchCommand", new SearchCommand());
   }

   //only to prevent your next question: How to recive the committed form
   @RequestMapping("/maingeo.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView handleSearch(SearchCommand searchCommand) {
      ... implement the search stuff
   } 
}


<form:form method="post" action="maingeo.html" command="searchCommand">
```

Comment: thanks for replying quickly, i had this class and all attribut match fiels form, the name used for the Command-Object in the Model put commandName also, but there is always this execption ! it seems focus this line : <form:label path="codeZone"><spring:message code="label.area"/></form:label>   and main reason : neither-bindingresult...

Comment: @user3248251: Add a system.out.println to the `goSearchArea()` method, and check if it is really invoked.

Comment: i deleted the first one, always this exception